# Django should I manage users in a separate django-app?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, keycloak, django-authentication

In Django 2.2, if I plan to make authentication its own service in the future and serve requests through DRF, should I put my User model in a separate app from my regular "functional apps and models"?

There's no way each app should contain its own implementation of auth, right?

**UPDATE**: I ultimately plan to use Keycloak for auth so that I can easily SSO.

```
Project_Root
|--app_access
|--app_shipper
|--app_cleaner
```

Comment: I'm going to call the app "access" because ".auth" could overlap with "django.auth". Seems like lots of people are calling their auth app "accounts", but that sounds too much like customers. I guess access isn't very pluralizable though.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

If you use the default Django authentication, you will notice that Permission, Group, User models are grouped together in one app.

Comment: Oh. Are Permission and Group built into Django? If so, did not know about them beyond User.

Comment: Check this Django documentation to use default authentication with permissions and groups. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/